# How to repeat groups of letters

Tags: r

I want to create a column with the letters A-D repeating 5 times, but I want to repeat each letter 5 times, not repeat A-D 5 times. For example, I want `A A A A A` `B B B B B` etc, NOT  `A B C D` `A B C D`. This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work.

```
data$group <- rep(c("A",5), ("B",5), ("C",5), ("D",5))
```

I get the error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "helpd$Group <- rep(c("A",5), ("B","
```

So something is wrong with my syntax. Anybody know the appropriate syntax?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `each = ...` option in `rep`

```
> rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 5)
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D" "D"
[20] "D"
```